# Add invalid parameters dynamically to Joi validation

Tags: reactjs, joi

I have a form that uses Joi for validation in the front and backend of a SPA, using React/redux, react-validation-mixin & joi-validation-strategy for the validation in the front. The Schema is connected to this.validatorTypes in the constructor

Depending on the input to the database from other users I might want to reject the input of a field (username is already taken)

After passing the error to the frontend I want the input field to be invalidated (since it still has the rejected value). I would like to add the value as invalid to the validation scheme.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give specific code help without seeing your code, but in general yes it is possible to update a schema. Here's a totally contrived example:

```
const keyFields = {
    username: Joi.string().required()
};
let formSchema = Joi.object().keys(keyFields);

// in some async req/res handler:
function handleApiResponse(badFormValue) {
    // badFormValue === { key: 'username', value: 'bad Value'}

    keyFields[badFormValue.key] = keyFields[badFormValue.key].invalid(badFormValue.value);

    formSchema = Joi.object().keys(keyFields);
}
```